# Twitter X using Font Awesome 6 not working

Tags: font-awesome

Why does the Twitter X icon not work in this code using Font Awesome 6? Any help is appreciated.

This is the link to the Font Awesome 6 Twitter X details: https://fontawesome.com/icons/x-twitter?f=brands&s=solid

Why does the Twitter X icon not work in this code using Font Awesome 6? Any help is appreciated.

This is the link to the Font Awesome 6 Twitter X details: https://fontawesome.com/icons/x-twitter?f=brands&s=solid

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
          <i
            class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f fa-xl"
            title="Facebook"
            alt="Facebook"
          ></i
        ></a>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com">
          <i
            class="fa-brands fa-youtube fa-xl"
            title="You Tube"
            alt="You Tube"
          ></i
        ></a>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="https://twitter.com">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-x-twitter fa-xl" title="X" alt="X"></i
        ></a>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="https://twitter.com"
          ><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-xl" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter"></i
        ></a>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com">
          <i
            class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-xl"
            title="Instagram"
            alt="Instagram"
          ></i
        ></a>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-tiktok fa-xl" title="Tik Tok" alt="Tik Tok"></i
        ></a>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com">
          <i
            class="fa-brands fa-linkedin fa-xl"
            title="Linkedin"
            alt="Linkedin"
          ></i
        ></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please notice the little box below the snippet on the linked page - it tells you this is part of FontAwesome since v6.4.2. When you load v6.2.1, it's obvious that it cannot contain the given icon

Comment: Thank you! I did not see that!

Answer (score 1):

It works with the font-awesome 6.4.2 version